# Argument 'context' cannot be null in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have used to use facebook login button for 5 months in my application and it's working normally until today , this error just showed up by today.

Stack Trace:

```
 STACK_TRACE=java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'context' cannot be null
at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:76)
at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(Utility.java:594)
at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>(AppEventsLogger.java:757)
at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>(AppEventsLogger.java:732)
at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.newLogger(AppEventsLogger.java:400)
at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.logButtonCreated(FacebookButtonBase.java:225)
at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.onAttachedToWindow(FacebookButtonBase.java:136)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14624)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1395)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1138)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6227)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:884)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:870)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:682)
```